# Where can students ask for professional volunteer assistance?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, students

I'm a student and a member of our high school's newly founded robotics team, which we are currently trying to get off the ground. We've gotten past our first major hurdle, obtaining the sizable sum of money needed to enter into the NASA FIRST Robotics competition.

Now, however, we're looking for mentors to help us build and program. Is there a place to do this on Stack Exchange? I've heard of Careers, but if I understand correctly, that's more for professionals and you have to pay to post there.

We're asking around for some local businesses, but most of them have said no, but we'll keep trying!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way would probably to put an advertisement in your "About Me" section.  Since you are an established user, people will be able to read it with just a mouseover.

As an aside, check with local technology companies, that's where we always were able to find volunteer engineers to help with the FIRST competition.

Comment: How did you guys do at FIRST?

Comment: This was eons ago, during the first few years of the competition, but one of our teams made it to the nationals in Florida.  It's very worthwhile, you'll learn a ton.

Comment: Companies are always willing to do this kind of stuff for free PR and publicity, so keep trying if you get a negative answer.

Answer (score 3):

No, that isn't really what these sites are for.  They're just for specific questions and answers.  Careers is just for job seekers.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider contacting a local university or college. [It appears that a local university has a computer science department](http://www.cs.unc.edu/) and an assistant professor who might just be the guy you're looking for, specializing in [medical robotics](http://www.cs.unc.edu/cms/our-people/faculty/ron-alterovitz/?searchterm=robotics).

Also good on you and your classmates for taking this initiative. Best of luck.